# Правильная обработка неудачно выделенной памяти

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь обработать исключение при невыделенной памяти. Под отладкой для указателя на структуру память выделена(имеется адрес), а для членов структуры - не выделена(типы данных структуры приведу ниже). try-catch не ловит не под каким видом. Ниже скриншот с кусочком try блока + код структуры:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
unsigned long  Data1;
unsigned short Data2;
unsigned short Data3;
unsigned char  Data4[ 8 ];
} GUID;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.: в том и дело, что члены структуры - не указатели.

Comment: @Abyx беда. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Abyx однако, студия предложила не останавливать при таких исключениях программу, и try - блок успешно обработал эту ошибку. Это является плохим стилем написания кода или можно воспользоваться им?

Comment: Это отсутствие понимания существа дела

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать __try/__except для обработки SEH.

Пример:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    __try
    {
        int *p = nullptr;
        *p = 22;
    }
    __except (GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
    {
        std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

http://rextester.com/LOXY44994

Подробнее на MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/swezty51.aspx

Comment: Однако огромное спасибо :)